# how to i enable update firstName in my test

Tags: java, unit-testing

hello so my test are not updating the first name and i dont know why.

```
    package ContactService;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ContactService {
     //Start with an ArrayList of contacts to hold the list of contacts
     ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();


     //Adds a new contact using the Contact constructor, then assign the new contact to the list.
    public void addContact(String firstName, String lastName, String number, String address) {
       // Create the new contact
       Contact contact = new Contact(firstName, lastName, number, address);
       contactList.add(contact);
    }
    public boolean updateContact(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String address)
{
    //run through loop again
    for (Contact contactList : contactList){
        //if contactID matches, run through each with making sure not "" and meets requirements
        //then return true as it did equal update.
        if(!firstName.equals("") && !(firstName.length()>10)){
            contactList.setFirstName(firstName);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

here is my test:

```
    void testUpdateFirstName() {
       ContactService service = new ContactService();
       service.addContact("Dr.", "Cross", "5555551111", "123 Lollypop Lane");
       service.updateContact("Sven","0","0","0");
       service.displayContactList();
       assertEquals("Sven",service.updateContact("0", "0", "0", "0"), "First name was not updated.");
    }
```

when i run it, it only displays the Dr. as the first name when i tried to change it to Sven.

Comment: "Contact contactList : contactList" How is this statement working? You are basically using same variable name for the list as well as the individual contacts
Moreover is your assertEquals statement you are matching "Sven" with service.updateContact which returns boolean value. So that should never work.

Comment: so I changed the Contact contact : contactList. but how would I change the updateContact in order for it to work and change Dr. to sven. i am very new at this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JUnit 4, the signature of the assertEquals method is:

```
assertEquals(String message, Object expected, Object actual)
```

So you need to change the assertion line to something like this:

```
assertEquals("First name was not updated.", true, service.updateContact("0", "0", "0", "0"));
```

---

If you are using JUnit 5 (aka Jupiter), the signature of the assertEquals method is:

```
assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual, String message)
```

So you need to change the assertion line to something like this:

```
assertEquals(true, service.updateContact("0", "0", "0", "0"), "First name was not updated.");
```